# Grid-based editing for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if there were a grid-based editor for SQL Server that simply let you work within a spreadsheet-type interface and key information directly into the sheet (like Access used to let you).

I need something quick to use when I'm creating test data, and considering I have about 9 other jobs to do at once, this seemed like the best bet..

Comment: "I need something quick to use when I'm creating test data" - I do this by writing TSQL. It has the added benefit of being repeatable...

Comment: I'm also wondering how this is directly programming related?

Comment: @Mitch http://stackoverflow.com/faq **What kind of questions can I ask here?** (3) software tools commonly used by programmers (4) matters that are unique to the programming profession

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: from first paragraph of that link: "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them"

Comment: So this is not a "best question", but is it valid? - yes.

Comment: Yeah sometimes programmers need silly dead simple apps or tools that pop up, do the job, and close. I usually write AHK, but this time just wanted that simple thing Access and SSMS do in so bloated a fashion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx)

1. Connect to a database from the Object Explorer.
2. Expand the database node
3. Expand the Tables node
4. Right click the table and click Edit
5. Type in the values you want
6. When you navigate away from the row, the data is committed

Comment: Hi, I develop SSMSBoost add-in for SSMS and in recent version (2.14) I have added the possibility to right-click the table name directly in SQL Editor and select "Edit top N rows". So only 1 action instead of 1-4.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Management Studio can edit rows.  Just right click on the table in the list of database objects and click Edit Top 200 Rows..   And SQL Management Studio Express is free. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to expand the tree in SSMS to

`Server \ Databases \ Tables \ <target table>`

Right-click on the table, choose "Edit top 200 rows"

You can then use the grid to add/edit data.  If you need to work with another range, right click on the grid, Pane > SQL - edit the statement to bring in the range desired.  Note however that the query must still be able to uniquely identify the source row for the grid to remain editable.

You can also get it to be more Access like by right-clicking and choosing `Pane > Criteria`.